# DevExtreme Charts - Set number of ticks on the valueAxis (y axis)

Tags: javascript, angular, devextreme

We have charts like the two below:

[image]
[image]

Notice that both charts have different number of ticks on the y axis:
7 ticks from 0 to 180,000
10 ticks from $0 to $1,000

Is it possible to set a fixed number of ticks so we could always have the first tick at 0 and the other values spread into just 5 more ticks?

6 ticks from 0 to 180,000
6 ticks from $0 to $1,000

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `tickInterval` property on the `valueAxis` settings. See this codepen for an example. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzwomL

For a more visual approach, you could also play around with the `axisDevisionFactor`. Here is the documention on that https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/valueAxis/tickInterval/

Comment: We have a few scenarios that are a bit more complex than this, including radio buttons to toggle formats (percent / fixedPoint) and types (fullstackedarea / stackedarea) of the chart, making it a real challenge.

I also tried a few things and with the data that we have, it's not always possible to fully control the # of ticks, unless we increase the size (height) of the chart, but that's not necessarily what we want/need.

Your answer is correct though, so I'll mark it as such and will get back to this problem when I have more time. Tks!